# Masquerading a Webserver

Tags: web-server, linux-networking, network-monitoring

I was trying to gain access to a piece of obsolete network hardware by intercepting into the configuration information that it is downloading from a remote server(with a public IP - This server exists no more though). Once the device boots up it sends a HTTP get request to the remote server. I was able to identify the IP address of this server (by capturing the network interface). How do I mimic a http webserver in my local machine so that when this get request is made to the remote server my local webserver responds to it instead (with my custom configuration information) Can I accomplish this with Perl's [HTTP::Server::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/HTTP-Server-Simple-0.44/lib/HTTP/Server/Simple.pm) ? Please suggest some reading which will be helpful.

[image: The image belongs to Microsoft]

I am using a topology like the picture above. Assuming 5 is the device I am talking about (Ignore the two client machines.) Can I intercept the traffic flowing from eth5 port to eth3 port on the host machine running Linux ? How do I go about snooping the connection between the ports and injecting traffic into it. The original question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18621261/masquerading-a-webserver) was recommended to be moved here. [The image belongs to Microsoft]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you have the IP address it is trying to connect to, just add it as an alias to an interface on eth port 5. Then your machine will now answer as that IP address and you should be able to use any HTTP server to send the file back.

On the linux box  assuming you have an ethernet interfaces called eth0 and eth1. Eth0 is connected to your upstream(ISP,CableModem,DSL,etc...), and eth1 is your local network.   what you would do is.

`sudo ifconfig eth1:0 ip.address.you.need up`

Now assuming that the linux box is the default GW for your lan, when any device on the lan tries to access `ip.address.you.need`  your box will answer, since it will show up in its routing tables as a '/32' route so it will not even go out to the internet.   Then all you need to do is setup a webserver to listen on that IP address and you can server whatever files you need back.

If you need to make it permanent, would need to know which version of linux you are using as each version is slightly different on where to configure it.

Comment: Could you please clarify it a bit more ?

Comment: I updated it, does that help

Comment: Thanks it helps. Can I perform this dynamically so that my local machine responds to a particular HTTP request(using a sequence number) ? Everything else the remote server responds ?

Comment: well that would be a bit harder using this(I suggested this way since you said the server IP didn't exist anymore)..   Since this server wouldn't be able to talk to the remote server if it had the same Ip that you aliased.  If it had a different IP address you could proxy to the other server.  The other option would be to drop the alias, and then use something like squid in a transparent proxy mode, perhaps coupled with an ICAP server if you need to do response modification.